# pushing different UITabBarControllers based on options selected in a UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am looking to design the following iphone screen flow that adheres to iOS App guidelines.

1) User selects one of 2 options in a `UIViewcontroller`. Ideally that is encapsulated in a `UINavigationController`.
2) Each option represents a very distinct workflow and in turn has a distinct set of tabs that is represented via `UITabBarController`.

Would the above design adhere to iOS App guidelines. If not what would be the best way to represent the above workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is totally doable.

- Create a new project: Single View Application
- Open Storyboard and select the ViewController
- Editor / Embeded In / navigation Controller
- Add two UIButtons to your project
- Add 2 TabBarControllers to ypur project
- Connect every TabBarController to one UIBUtton through Segue Push
- Ready. Your idea was drawn.

The result in this image.

[image]

An example project [here](https://github.com/GabrielMassana/OneNavBar_With_2TabBar).

Comment: Thank you Gabriel ..this is helpful. I also found that changing the tab bar programmatically based on value of the viewcontroller that itself is in one of the tabs (but tabbar hidden) was another approach.